# How can I split part of a string that is inconsistent?

Tags: c#

I have the following string:

`01-21-27-0000-00-048` and it is easy to split it apart because each section is separated by a `-`, but sometimes this string is represented as `01-21-27-0000-00048`, so splitting it is not as easy because the last 2 parts are combined.  How can I handle this?  Also, what about the case where it might be something like `01-21-27-0000-00.048`

In case anyone is curious, this is a parcel number and it varies from county to county and a county can have 1 format or they can have 100 formats.

Comment: Why not just strip out all dashes and periods, and then select the appropriate substrings?

Comment: In the second case it's "separated" by 0? I ask because the last token is `000048` instead of `00-048`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I think in the second case it's not separated by anything?

Comment: Is the pattern of digits always going to be 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3? If so, the first comment suggestion would work. If not, then you need a craftier solution. The second example is going to prove problematic under such a scenario, as well, if the digits are not consistent.

Comment: It's difficult to come up with an answer to this question without knowing the range of possible formats or the significance of the various parts of the string.  For example, would `00048` always be equivalent to `00-048`, or might it also represent `000-48`?

Comment: No, the pattern can vary, but is consistent for per customer.  The "0" in the second case is not a seperator

Comment: Use `var parts = "01-21-27-0000-00-048".Split(new char[] { '-' }, 5);` and handle `parts[4]` separately.

Comment: If the pattern is consistent for each customer, then store some definition of the pattern for each customer, and use that to split the string.  Regular expressions come to mind.

Comment: @phoog - This was my approach I was going to take.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very good case for using regular expressions. You string matches the following regexp:

```
(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})-(\d{2})[.-]?(\d{3})
```

Match the input against this expression, and harvest the six groups of digits from the match:

```
var str = new[] {
    "01-21-27-0000-00048", "01-21-27-0000-00.048", "01-21-27-0000-00-048"
};
foreach (var s in str) {
    var m = Regex.Match(s, @"(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})-(\d{2})[.-]?(\d{3})");
    for (var i = 1 /* one, not zero */ ; i != m.Groups.Count ; i++) {
        Console.Write("{0} ", m.Groups[i]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

If you would like to allow for other characters, say, letters in the segments that are separated by dashes, you could use `\w` instead of `\d` to denote a letter, a digit, or an underscore. If you would like to allow an unspecified number of such characters within a known range, say, two to four, you can use `{2,4}` in the regexp instead of the more specific `{2}`, which means "exactly two". For example,

```
(\w{2,3})-(\w{2})-(\w{2})-(\d{4})-(\d{2})[.-]?(\d{3})
```

lets the first segment contain two to three digits or letters, and also allow for letters in segments two and three.

Comment: I have thought about this. They may not be numbers all the time though and some parts can be between 2 and 3 chars

Comment: @Xaisoft - that would be useful information to post in your original question so people aren't guessing at your intent.

Comment: @Xaisoft Then you need to come up with a defined set of rules that all of your data will fall into. Until you do that you won't be able to come up with the correct solution. I was about to post the same answer as this but using named groups in the regex as I prefer that: `^(?<first>\d{2})-(?<second>\d{2})-(?<third>\d{2})-(?<fourth>\d{4})-(?<fifth>\d{2})[\.-]?(?<sixth>\d{3})$`

Comment: @Xaisoft That's even better: regex can easily handle small variations like that.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - How can I modify it to handle something like:  `20G-34-41-01-00003.G-0020.04`

Comment: Also, in the case above, the first part could be `20G` or `20' and the other parts such as 34, 41, and 01 can have letters as well, so should I look for the numbers first and then the char or put it together in the expression

Answer (score 2):

Normalize the string first.

I.e. if you know that the last part is always three characters, then insert a - as the fourth-to-last character, then split the resultant string. Along the same line, convert the dot '.' to a dash '-' and split that string.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all the char which are not digit with **emptyString**('').

then any of your string become in the format like

`012127000000048`

now you can use the divide it in (2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3) parts.